# Drawing NES Link in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am currently remaking NES Zelda in assembly and for some reason, I can't display the character properly.

```
    IDEAL
    MODEL small
    STACK 100h
    DATASEG
    CODESEG
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    BACKGROUND_COLOR DB 5Ah ; Guessed randomly for more than half an hour
    LINK_X DW 94h
    LINK_Y DW 64h
    start_x DB 00h
    start_y DB 00h
    x DW 0000h
    y DW 0000h
    cloop DB 0000h
    link_sprite:
        DB 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h
        DB 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 00h, 00h, 00h
        DB 00h, 00h, 2Ah, 00h, 02h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 02h, 00h, 2Ah, 00h
        DB 00h, 00h, 2Ah, 00h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 00h, 2Ah, 00h
        DB 00h, 00h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h, 2Ah, 02h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 02h, 2Ah, 06h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 00h
        DB 00h, 00h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 00h
        DB 00h, 00h, 00h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h, 00h
        DB 00h, 00h, 00h, 02h, 02h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 02h, 02h, 06h, 00h
        DB 00h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 02h, 02h, 06h, 06h, 06h
        DB 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h
        DB 06h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 02h, 02h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h
        DB 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 02h, 02h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h
        DB 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 02h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah
        DB 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 2Ah, 00h
        DB 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 00h, 00h, 00h
        DB 00h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h, 00h, 00h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 00h, 00h, 00h
        DB 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h
        
    
    mov ah, 00h ; Changes to display mode (who needs text?)
    mov al, 13h ; Changes screen resolution to 320x200 with 256 color options, for best display
    int 10h     ; Flushes the display mode

    mov ah, 06h    ; Changes to scroll up (so it can start drawing the background from the top)
    xor al, al     ; Clear entire screen because the terminal has already drew the screen black
    xor cx, cx     ; Moves to the upper left corner
    mov dx, 184Fh  ; Gets screen size
    mov bh, [BACKGROUND_COLOR]    ; Paints the screen the background color
    int 10h

    proc draw_link
        mov ax, [LINK_X]
        mov [x], ax
        mov ax, [LINK_Y]
        mov [y], ax
        mov [cloop], 00h
        mov si, offset link_sprite
        linkmainloop:
            mov al, [si]
            mov ah, 0Ch         ; Changes to pixel writing
            mov cx, [x]   ; Sets X Coordinates for the pixel
            mov dx, [y]   ; Sets Y Coordinates for the pixel
            int 10h            ; Flushes the pixel
            add [x], 1h
            mov ax, [LINK_X]
            sub [x], ax
            cmp [x], 0Fh
            je breakline
            repeat:
                add si, 1h
                add [x], ax
                add [cloop], 1h
                cmp [cloop], 0FFh
                jne linkmainloop
                jmp wait_for_wasd
        breakline:
            sub [x], 0Fh
            add [y], 1h
            jmp repeat
    endp

    wait_for_wasd:
        mov ax, 0000h         ; resetting so it will not loop endlessly, saying that from trial and error :(
        int 16h             ; Get keystroke
        cmp ax, 1177h       ; 1177h == scancode for W
        je link_up
        cmp ax, 1E61h       ; 1E61h == scancode for A
        je link_left
        cmp ax, 1F73h       ; 1F73h == scancode for S
        je link_down
        cmp ax, 2064h       ; 2064h == scancode for D
        je link_right
        jmp wait_for_wasd

    link_up:
        mov al, [BACKGROUND_COLOR]
        call draw_pixel
        cmp [y], 0h
        je up_border
        sub [y], 01h
        mov al, 2h
        call draw_pixel
        jmp wait_for_wasd

    link_left:
        mov al, [BACKGROUND_COLOR]
        call draw_pixel
        cmp [x], 0h
        je left_border
        sub [x], 01h
        mov al, 2h
        call draw_pixel
        jmp wait_for_wasd
    
    link_down:
        mov al, [BACKGROUND_COLOR]
        call draw_pixel
        cmp [y], 0C7h
        je down_border
        add [y], 01h
        mov al, 2h
        call draw_pixel
        jmp wait_for_wasd

    link_right:
        mov al, [BACKGROUND_COLOR]
        call draw_pixel
        cmp [x], 13Fh
        je right_border
        add [x], 1h
        mov al, 2h
        call draw_pixel
        jmp wait_for_wasd
    
    right_border:
        mov [x], 0h
        ret
    down_border:
        mov [y], 0h
        ret
    up_border:
        mov [y], 0C7h
        ret
    left_border:
        mov [x], 13Fh
        ret

    draw_pixel:
    ; remember to set al before calling this function
        ;mov al, 10h
        mov ah, 0Ch         ; Changes to pixel writing
        mov bh, 00h         ; The page number is 00, we don't have other pages yet
        mov cx, [x]   ; Sets X Coordinates for the pixel
        mov dx, [y]   ; Sets Y Coordinates for the pixel
        int 10h            ; Flushes the pixel
        ret

END start
```

But it prints this out:
[image: Representation of code output]

I tried changing many things for hours but nothing seems to work. For some reason, when I put my sprite sheet inside my friend's code it magically works, but when I start inputting my own code in his' (so I'll know what's the problem) it returns to being this weird mess.

His code (with my sprite sheet):

```
IDEAL

MODEL small

STACK 256

DATASEG
x_offset dw 94h
y_offset dw 64h

; we define the plane in an array of BIOS colors
plane DB 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h
        DB 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 00h, 00h, 00h
        DB 00h, 00h, 2Ah, 00h, 02h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 02h, 00h, 2Ah, 00h
        DB 00h, 00h, 2Ah, 00h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 00h, 2Ah, 00h
        DB 00h, 00h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h, 2Ah, 02h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 02h, 2Ah, 06h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 00h
        DB 00h, 00h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 00h
        DB 00h, 00h, 00h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h, 00h
        DB 00h, 00h, 00h, 02h, 02h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 02h, 02h, 06h, 00h
        DB 00h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 02h, 02h, 06h, 06h, 06h
        DB 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h
        DB 06h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 02h, 02h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h
        DB 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 02h, 02h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h
        DB 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 02h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah
        DB 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 2Ah, 00h
        DB 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 06h, 06h, 06h, 2Ah, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 02h, 00h, 00h, 00h
        DB 00h, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 2Ah, 06h, 00h, 00h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 00h, 00h, 00h
        DB 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 06h, 06h, 06h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h
cloop dw 00h
x dw 00h
y dw 00h

CODESEG

proc move_to_graphics_mode
    mov ah, 00h ;enter graphics mode
    mov al, 13h
    int 10h
;    mov ax, 13h
;    int 10h
;    ret
endp

proc change_bg_color
    mov ax, 0600h
    mov bh, 1fh
    mov cx, 0000h
    mov dx, 184fh
    int 10h
    ret
endp

; will use bh for color
proc color_pixel
    push si
    push dx
    push cx
    
    mov ah, 0ch ;write a pixel
    mov al, bh ;color
    mov si, offset x_offset
    mov cx, [si] ;x value
    mov si, offset y_offset
    mov dx, [si] ;y value
    int 10h
    
    pop cx
    pop dx
    pop si
    ret
endp

proc delete_plane
    ret
endp

proc draw_plane
    mov ax, [x_offset]
    mov [x], ax
    mov ax, [y_offset]
    mov [y], ax
    mov [cloop], 00h
    mov si, offset plane
    planemainloop:
        mov al, [si]
        mov ah, 0Ch         ; Changes to pixel writing
        mov bh, 00h         ; The page number is 00, we don't have other pages yet
        mov cx, [x]   ; Sets X Coordinates for the pixel
        mov dx, [y]   ; Sets Y Coordinates for the pixel
        int 10h            ; Flushes the pixel
        add [x], 1h
        mov ax, [x_offset]
        sub [x], ax
        cmp [x], 0Fh
        jge breakline
        repeat:
            add si, 1h
            add [x], ax
            add [cloop], 1h
            cmp [cloop], 0FFh
            jne planemainloop
            jmp move_when_spacebar_pressed
    breakline:
        sub [x], 0Fh
        add [y], 1h
        jmp repeat
endp

proc generate_bullet
    ; generate bullet
    ; empty for now
    ret
endp

proc move_when_spacebar_pressed
    mov ah, 0
    int 16h
    cmp al, ' '
    je spacebar_pressed
    jmp exitfunc

    spacebar_pressed:
        mov si, offset x_offset
        mov ax, [si]
        inc ax
        mov [si], ax
        mov bh, 0100b
        call color_pixel
    exitfunc:
        call color_pixel
        ret
endp

Start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    call move_to_graphics_mode
 ;   call change_bg_color
    call draw_plane
    mov bh, 0100b
    call color_pixel
    ;main_loop:
        ;call move_when_spacebar_pressed
        ;jmp main_loop


Exit:
END start
```

The output:[image: Friend's Output]

If someone knows what the issue is, and is willing to help me print my character good in my code I'll greatly appreciate it

Yours truly, Tomer

Comment: For starters, do not put your data in the middle of code execution path. All your stuff beginning with the `BACKGROUND_COLOR` up to the sprite should be in the `DATASEG` block.

Comment: I'm not at home right now, but I'll try that when I get home. Thanks ahead!

Comment: WOW IT ACTUALLY WORKED!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! a big upvote from me